# Errno 22: Invalid argument while using tiff.imread() in python

Tags: python, tiff, imread, invalid-argument

I have a folder with ~800 tiff images. i wrote the following code to save these as multiple tiff stacks of 220 images each. In a later section of this code, i try to open the tiff stacks that I've saved using tiff.imread() but I get the Error[22] Invalid Argument.

My import functions:

```
import numpy as np
import scipy as sp
import matplotlib as mpl
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import pandas as pd
import sys
import tifffile as tiff
from skimage import io
import cv2
import tifftools
from tifffile import imread, imsave
from tifffile import TiffWriter, memmap
```

```
image_stack =[]

tiff_files = math.ceil(len(list_of_images)/220)  ## each tiff file to be 220 images long
print(tiff_files)

if tiff_files >1:
    for i in range(tiff_files-1):
        print(i)
        
        image_stack =[]
        for j in range(220):
            print(j)
            image_r = imread(wrk_dir + list_of_images[j+i*220])
            image_stack.append(image_r)
        tiff.imwrite(output_dir + str(i)+'.tif', image_stack)
        print(i,'done')
    
    image_stack =[]
    for j in range(len(list_of_images)-220*(tiff_files-1)):
        print(j)
        image_r = imread(wrk_dir + list_of_images[j+(tiff_files-1)*220])
        image_stack.append(image_r)
    tiff.imwrite(output_dir + str(tiff_files-1)+'.tif', image_stack)
    print(tiff_files-1,'done')
    
else:
    image_stack =[]
    for j in range(len(list_of_images)):
        print(j)
        image_r = imread(wrk_dir+ list_of_images[j])
        image_stack.append(image_r)
    tiff.imwrite(output_dir + str(tiff_files-1)+'.tif', image_stack)
    print(tiff_files-1,'done')
```

the code snippet where i try to read the tiff stack but then i get the error:

```
for i in range(tiff_files):
    print(i)
    # read all images matching the pattern
    image_stack = tiff.imread(output_dir+str(i)+'.tif')
```

I tried to open the tiff stacks but i got the invalid argument error. What can i do to solve this? Sometimes the same code works and sometimes it doesnt :/

Comment: Can you open the files with any other program? Can you open the files with the `open(...)` Python function?

Comment: Which tutorial or documentation are you following? Does it say that the library supports TIFF stacks?

Comment: Please put back your `import` statements so we know which packages you are using.

Comment: I cannot use Image.open() either and it gives the following error: UnidentifiedImageError: cannot identify image file 'G:/Shared drives/Chemistry/Projects/Proof-of-Concept/Integrated diffusion test/Thin reservoir-1kgel-1uL AB61-QD705-no MAPs_POC3-LP8_SU3/Analysis/2.tiff'  It may be because my image is a 16 bit image? @MarkSetchell

Comment: `G:/Shared drives`: Is this maybe a mounted network or shared cloud folder? In any case try to exclude the folders containing scientific TIFF files from Windows antivirus scanning and indexing. Those services are know to get stuck, timeout, crash, or hang on non-standard TIFF.

Comment: I got it to work - Yes you were right it was the network issue - i had to make the folder available offline and it worked perfectly. Thank you!